# Migrating Firebase project from custom auth, claims to native

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an existing Firebase project where I'm managing auth myself in a backend API. I'm hashing the password and comparing it to a stored hashed password and returning a custom claims token.

I'm trying to transition the project to using the native auth (sign in with email + password). My problem is the existing users. I have hashed passwords for all of them stored in Firebase, but the Firebase auth itself doesn't know about the passwords. I don't want to force my users to all set their passwords again, but I don't see another way to accomplish this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you know the key used to hash the passwords, since you stored them in Firestore. You could then use the [`auth:import`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import) command of the CLI.

Comment: Yep! I used this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/248 and this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_bcrypt_hashed_passwords to help understand. Thank you!